# SSIS XML source using dynamic variable provides no data

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I have an ssis package that is creating records in Dynamics 365, the source of the xml files is a dynamic variable coming from a for each loop.

The xml source doesn't seem to work although data tasks with the same variable name do.

The xml source doesn't validate metadata as the source needs to be a dynamic variable which is a blank string.

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Thank you.

[Xml Source properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1tEP.png)

Comment: I do not like the XML tool for SQL Server which has limited capabilities.  I have written in the past c# applications that reads an xml file and stores the parsed data into a SQL database (rather than storing the xml file a a single entity).

Comment: Same here. Usually I create own XML source components via C#. Either "simple" ones which parse the file and push the infos into the corresponding output columns or more complex ones under the use of XSLT stylesheets where again the results are pushed into the output columns.